# sanity blogs are not rendering in netlify

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, sanity

I just hosted my portfolio website on netlify for free and everything is working fine except the blogs page. The blogs as well as the blogPost page are not rendering. In the browser console I am getting some error but I haven't found any possible way to fix it. [This is my site](https://abhirupkumar.netlify.app/). I have used sanity.io as headless cms. On my local computer, when I run localhost:3000 it is working fine and the blogs are also rendering. By the way I have hosted my sanity studio too using sanity deploy and added the site name in CORS Origin.
This is my blogs page:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import { createClient } from "next-sanity";
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url'
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Navbar from '../components/NavBar';

const BlogPost = ({ blogs, profile }) => {

    const client = createClient({
        projectId: "***********",
        dataset: "production",
        useCdn: false
    });
    const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client)

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar profile={profile} />
            <div className="my-12" id="blog">
                <div className="container m-auto py-16 md:py-20 mb-8">
                    <h2 className="text-center font-header text-4xl font-semibold uppercase text-primary sm:text-5xl lg:text-6xl">
                        I also like to write
                    </h2>
                    <h4 className="pt-6 text-center font-header text-xl font-medium text-black sm:text-2xl lg:text-3xl">
                        Check out my latest posts!
                    </h4>
                    <div className="mx-auto grid w-full grid-cols-1 gap-6 pt-12 sm:w-3/4 lg:w-full lg:grid-cols-3 xl:gap-10">
                        {blogs && blogs.map((item) => {
                            return <Link key={item.slug.current} href={"/blogPost/" + item.slug.current} className="shadow">
                                <div>
                                    <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${builder.image(item.blogimage).width(200).url()})` }}
                                        className="group relative h-72 bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat sm:h-84 lg:h-64 xl:h-72">
                                        <span
                                            className="absolute inset-0 block bg-gradient-to-b from-blog-gradient-from to-blog-gradient-to bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat opacity-10 transition-opacity group-hover:opacity-50"></span>
                                        <span className="absolute right-0 bottom-0 mr-4 mb-4 block rounded-full bg-primary border-2 border-primary px-6 py-2 text-center font-body text-sm font-bold uppercase md:text-base text-white cursor-pointer">Read More</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="bg-gray-100 py-6 px-5 xl:py-8 cursor-pointer">
                                        <span className="block font-body text-lg font-semibold text-black">{item.title}</span>
                                        <span className="block pt-2 font-body text-grey-20">{item.metadesc}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </Link>
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="bg-primary">
                <div className="container flex flex-col justify-between py-3 sm:flex-row">
                    <p className="font-body text-white md:text-left">
                        © Copyright 2022. All right reserved!
                    </p>
                    <div className="flex items-center justify-center pt-5 sm:justify-start sm:pt-0">
                        <a href="/">
                            <i className="bx bxl-facebook-square text-2xl text-white hover:text-yellow"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href={profile.linkedinlink} className="pl-4">
                            <i className="bx bxl-linkedin text-2xl text-white hover:text-yellow"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="/" className="pl-4">
                            <i className="bx bxl-instagram text-2xl text-white hover:text-yellow"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const client = createClient({
        projectId: "**********",
        dataset: "production",
        apiVersion: '*******',
        useCdn: false
    });

    const query = `*[_type == "blog"]`;
    const blogs = await client.fetch(query)
    const profileQuery = `*[_type == "profile"][0]`;
    const profile = await client.fetch(profileQuery)

    return {
        props: {
            blogs, profile
        },
    }
}


export default BlogPost
```

The blogPost folder has a [slug].js

```
import { createClient } from 'next-sanity'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import PortableText from 'react-portable-text'
import Navbar from '../../components/NavBar'

const Slug = ({ blog, profile }) => {

  const [date, setDate] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const date = new Date(blog.createdAt)
    setDate(date)
  }, [])
  

  return (
    <>
      <div>
      <Navbar profile={profile}/>
      <Head>
        <title>{blog && blog.title}</title>
      </Head>
        <div>
          <div className="container py-6 md:py-10 mt-16">
            <div className="mx-auto max-w-4xl">
              <div>
                <h1 className="pt-5 font-body text-3xl font-semibold text-primary sm:text-4xl md:text-5xl xl:text-6xl">{blog && blog.title}</h1>
                <div className="flex items-center pt-5 md:pt-10">
                  <div>
                    <img src="/Abhirup_animated_logo.jpeg" className="h-20 w-20 rounded-full border-2 border-grey-70 shadow" alt="author image" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="pl-5">
                    <span className="block font-body text-xl font-bold text-grey-10">By {profile.name}</span>
                    <span className="block pt-1 font-body text-xl font-bold text-grey-30">{date && date.toLocaleDateString("en-GB", { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' })}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="prose max-w-none pt-8">
                {blog && <PortableText
                  // Pass in block content straight from Sanity.io
                  content={blog.content}
                  projectId="eno1o1do"
                  dataset="production"
                  // Optionally override marks, decorators, blocks, etc. in a flat
                  // structure without doing any gymnastics
                  serializers={{
                    h1: (props) => <h1 style={{ color: "black" }} {...props} />,
                    img: ({ children }) => <img className="w-full">{ children }</img>,
                    li: ({ children }) => <li className="special-list-item">{ children }</li>
                  }}
                />}
              </div>
              
              <div className="mt-10 flex justify-between border-t border-lila py-12">
                <Link href={"/blogs"}><a className="flex items-center">
                  <i className="bx bx-left-arrow-alt text-2xl text-primary"></i>
                  <span className="block pr-2 font-body text-lg font-bold uppercase text-primary md:pr-5">Checkout More Blogs</span>
                </a>
                </Link>
              </div>
              <div
                className="flex flex-col items-center border-t border-lila py-12 pt-12 md:flex-row md:items-start xl:pb-20">
                <div className="w-3/4 sm:w-2/5 lg:w-1/4 xl:w-1/5">
                  <img src="/Abhirup_animated_logo.jpeg" className="rounded-full shadow" alt="author image" />
                </div>
                <div className="ml-0 text-center md:ml-10 md:w-5/6 md:text-left">
                  <h3 className="pt-10 font-body text-2xl font-bold text-secondary md:pt-0">
                    Abhirup Kumar Bhowmick
                  </h3>
                  <p
                    className="pt-5 font-body text-lg leading-8 text-secondary sm:leading-9 md:text-xl md:leading-9 lg:leading-9 xl:leading-9">
                    Hey guys, I'm a 2nd year CSE undergrad student. I am really interested in freelancing and passionate about making new softwares which adds values to peoples life. I write blogs which might help you discover new aspects of various technologies.

                  </p>
                  <div className="flex items-center justify-center pt-5 md:justify-start">
                    <a href="/">
                      <i className="bx bxl-facebook-square text-2xl text-primary hover:text-yellow"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href={profile.linkedinlink} className="pl-4">
                      <i className="bx bxl-linkedin text-2xl text-primary hover:text-yellow"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="/" className="pl-4">
                      <i className="bx bxl-instagram text-2xl text-primary hover:text-yellow"></i>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="bg-primary">
          <div className="container flex flex-col justify-between py-6 sm:flex-row">
            <p className="text-center font-body text-white md:text-left">
              © Copyright 2022. All rights reserved.
            </p>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center pt-5 sm:justify-start sm:pt-0">
              <a href="/">
                <i className="bx bxl-facebook-square text-2xl text-white hover:text-yellow"></i>
              </a>
              <a href={profile.linkedinlink}  className="pl-4">
                <i className="bx bxl-linkedin text-2xl text-white hover:text-yellow"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="/" className="pl-4">
                <i className="bx bxl-instagram text-2xl text-white hover:text-yellow"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div >
    </>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  // It's important to default the slug so that it doesn't return "undefined"
  const { slug } = context.query
  const client = createClient({
    projectId: "**********",
    dataset: "production",
    apiVersion: '**********',
    useCdn: false
  });

  const query = `*[_type == "blog" && slug.current == "${slug}"][0]`;
  const blog = await client.fetch(query)
  
  const profileQuery = `*[_type == "profile"][0]`;
  const profile = await client.fetch(profileQuery)
  return {
    props: {
      blog, profile
    }
  }
}

export default Slug
```

After hosting the website on netlify, the blogs and blogPost pages are not working. How to fix it?

Comment: Please add the code in the question

Answer (score 1):

In your `astro.config.mjs` you need to verify this key: `output: "?",` and it should be static as its value, if the value of the output key is "server", just change the value to "static" and should work fine in your netlify deploy. Hope it works for you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).